# Remotely work on Red Hat Box

Tags: ubuntu, rhel, remote-desktop, remote-management

So we're working on a project and currently,have the need to edit/save files remotely on a Red Hat box.
We are accessing this files mainly with sublime-text.
So we are trying to figure out what is the best option to do this, for example:
To have a folder on the ~user/remoteShare
and to be able to edit/save/delete any file under this remote folder from my local sublime-text editor

I'm using local Ubuntu 14.04 and Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 on the remote.

Comment: You've fundamentally changed the question with your edit. Try and avoid that if there are already answers present.

Comment: Since the edit, this question basically becomes a duplicate of [this question over on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958056/how-to-use-sublime-over-ssh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best options will be to use X forwarding, vnc, or [noMachine](https://www.nomachine.com)

In all practicality, If you need to remotely access a server over a gui, your workflow likely has room for improvement. If your company grows above one or two servers, using a gui will be impractical.

This is exactly why there are system automation tools:

- [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com)   + [mcollective](http://puppetlabs.com/mcollective)
- [chef](http://www.getchef.com/chef/)
- [ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home)
- [rundeck](http://rundeck.org)

**Update**
Since the question was rephrased, I'll address the new question.

If you have a file that multiple users need to edit, you could create a network mount point. However this will not prevent users from stepping on each others toes and overwriting each other.

A far better solution is to put the file inside version control (svn, hg, git) and then make users commit their changes. I highly recommend looking at git.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're thinking of X11 forwarding via SSH where the Xclients on the server connect to your desktop's `xorg` server. You can either let it connect to your local xorg if you're on a Unix workstation, or if you're on Windows there's a program called [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) that will run one for you and you can [configure Putty to forward X11 to that.](http://www.geo.mtu.edu/geoschem/docs/putty_install.html).

Be warned that since the clients are running on the remote server and just transmitting their drawing instructions to your local computer, you'll still have to install a fair number of GUI-related packages on the server even with this option. This only gets you out of consuming resources running a graphical display server 24/7 and installing the graphic server-related packages.

Comment: you are right; I overlooked that detail